# how to access the next item in the list in lambda expressions

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I am creating a simple query (if this is even the term of using LINQ) that takes each number in the list, added is to the index, and then from the new list I want to divide the value with the highest index with the value that has the highest index - 1 and then do that same action on all the indexes in the pairs (index val, index val-1) so the result will be a list half a size of the original list, and then pick the highest result from the new list.

```cs
 var lst = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

   var fianle = lst
               .Select((value, i) => new { i, value })
               .Select(item =>
          item.value + item.i)
             .Select((x , how to accse the previos item? ) => x/previositem)
            .Max(x => x);
```

so i want to know

1. how to loop backward using lambda expressions
2. how to access the previous item in the list using lambda expressions

thank you in advance!

Comment: Side note: both `.ToList()` are redundant and can be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a property in your anonymous object to hold previous one:

```
var listWithPrevious = lst
               .Select((value, i) => 
                          new { 
                                Index = i,
                                Value = value,
                                Previous = lst.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1) 
                              });
```

and then use the collection above to do what ever is required.

You can modify your code to be like:

```
var fianle = lst
           .Select((value, i) => 
                         new { 
                                Index = i,
                                Value = value,
                                Previous = lst.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1) 
                              })
           .Select(item =>
      item.value + item.i)
         .Select((x , Previous ) => x/Previous)
        .Max(x => x);
```

Comment: `Previous = list.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1)`

Comment: is that the full query?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko agreed, and Guilhem the indexer can fail too

Comment: @avivgood3 no it's just to give idea, you can use it down for your output